R is multiplicative and integers $q$ for which every character mod $q$ is real
Recalling that a character $\chi$ mod $q$ is called real if $\chi(a) \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, i.e., if $\chi(a) \in \{-1, 1\}$ for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(a, q) = 1$.
(a) For a positive integer $q$, denote by $R(q)$ the number of real characters mod $q$. Prove that $R$ is a multiplicative arithmetic function, and compute $R(p^k)$ for every prime power $p^k$.
(b) Determine those positive integers $q$ such that every character mod $q$ is real.
I am having trouble with this. For (b) I have this:
Using theorem 2 to investigate $R(p^k)$ for prime powers.
Case 1: $q = 2^k$

For $k = 1$, we know $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^*$ is trivial, so there is only one character, and it is real. Hence, every character mod $2$ is real, and $R(2) = 1$.
For $k = 2$, $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order 2, and the only characters mod $4$ are real. Therefore, $R(4) = 1$, and all characters mod $4$ are real.
For $k \geq 3$, we have $(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^* = \langle -1 \rangle \times \langle 5 \rangle$, so not all characters are real. Hence, for $k \geq 3$, not all characters mod $2^k$ are real.

Thus, for $q = 2^k$, the only integers where all characters are real are $q = 2$ and $q = 4$.
Case 2: $q = p^k$ for $p \geq 3$
For $p \geq 3$, 2 tells us that $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$. There are more than just real characters in this group, so not all characters mod $p^k$ are real for $p \geq 3$. Hence, there are no prime powers $p^k$ for $p \geq 3$ where all characters are real.
Case 3:
If $q$ is composite and contains any prime factor $p \geq 3$ or if $q$ contains $2^k$ for $k \geq 3$, then not all characters mod $q$ can be real. This follows from Theorem 2, which tells us that the characters mod $q$ decompose into characters mod prime powers.
Thus, the only composite values of $q$ that could potentially have all real characters are powers of  $2$, so $4$ in this case.
The only positive integers $q$ such that every character mod $q$ is real are:
$$q = 2 \quad \text{and} \quad q = 4.$$
1) Please help me prove (a) or send me to any resource containing a proof
2) Is part (b)correct?

Theorems that I think can help:
Theorem 1.
Let $q = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_t^{k_t}$ where $p_1, \dots, p_t$ are distinct prime numbers and $k_1, \dots, k_t$ are positive integers. Then
$$
G(p_1^{k_1}) \times \cdots \times G(p_t^{k_t}) \to G(q) : (\chi_1, \dots, \chi_t) \mapsto \chi_1 \cdots \chi_t
$$
is a group isomorphism.
Theorem 2.
(i) Let $p$ be a prime $\geq 3$ and $k \geq 1$. Then the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$.
(ii) $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order 2.
Further, if $k \geq 3$ then $(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^* = \langle -1 \rangle \times \langle 5 \rangle$ is isomorphic to the direct product of a cyclic group of order 2 and a cyclic group of order $2^{k-2}$.

I will describe an approach to this whose main idea is to get away from the setting of characters.
When $A$ is a finite abelian group, let $\, \hat{\! A}$ be the group of characters $\chi : A \to S^1$. A character of $A$ is real exactly when it squares to the trivial character. So in the group $\, \hat{\! A}$, the real characters are the 2-torsion elements.
The finite abelian groups $A$ and $\, \hat{\! A}$ are (non-canonically) isomorphic, so to count $2$-torsion in $\, \hat{\! A}$ is the same as to count $2$-torsion in $A$.
We will apply this to the finite abelian groups $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^*$, whose characters are the Dirichlet characters mod $m$. Your $R(m)$ is the number of real Dirichlet characters mod $m$. By what I said above, we also have $R(m) = \#\{a \bmod m : a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod m\}$.
When $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, $(\mathbf Z/mn\mathbf Z)^* \cong (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^* \times (\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^*$ by the Chinese remainder theorem, so by counting $2$-torsion on both sides of this isomorphism we get $R(mn) = R(m)R(n)$.
To determine the $m$ such that all Dirichlet characters are real is the same as determining the $m$ such that all units $a \bmod m$ satisfy $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod m$, and I think it is simpler to think about that problem than the original problem of real characters.
Cauchy's theorem in group theory says prime factors of the order of a group always occur as orders of some elements in the group (this is simpler to show when the group is abelian than in the general finite group setting). Thus if all characters mod $m$ are real then the only prime factor of $\varphi(m)$ is $2$, i.e., $\varphi(m)$ is a power of $2$. You think the only such $m$ are $2$ and $4$, but this is incorrect: it also holds when $m$ has other values such as $3$, $8$, and $12$ (I am not saying those are the only values you missed!), so reconsider how you were determining when $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^*$ has only real characters. Work out when $\varphi(m)$ is a power of $2$ and then, among such $m$, when all elements of $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^*$ square to $1$.

When $m$ is 16 for example then $13^2$ is not 1 mod $16$. So I don't think it is enough for $\phi(m)$ to a power of $2$. Also I think there are more solutions, as in my answer.

Yes, I miswrote what I meant.  I have now edited the "if and only if" to be more accurate.

How do I compute $R(p^k)$ for $p$ prime?

That is the same as asking to count ${a \bmod p^k : a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod p^k}$.  Do this on your own when $p^k$ is a small power of a prime $p$, using a computer. The answer is different when $p  = 2$ and $p > 2$.

You can answer both questions using the following fact:

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and $H$ be a subgroup. Then a character $\chi$ on $H$ can be extended to a character $\chi^*$ on $G$ in $\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ ways.

For a proof see Theorem 3.4 in Keith Conrad's notes.
When $G=(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, $|G|=\phi(m)$. So the trivial character on the trivial group can be extended in $\frac{\phi(m)}{1}=\phi(m)$ ways. Therefore, the cardinality of all characters on $G$ is $\phi(m)$, a multiplicative function. This answers your first question.
For the second question, note that given $a$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, if the order of $a$ is bigger than $2$, then you can find a non-real character on the cyclic group generated by $a$. Then you can extend this to a charecter on  $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. This tells you that in order for all characters to be real we must have that $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is isomorphic to the trivial group or $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. If $m$ were a power of $2$, this would mean that $m$ is either $2,4, 8.$ Further, if the prime factorisation of $m$ contained $p^k$, odd $p$, then $p$ must be $3$ and $k$ must be $1$. Now, if $m$ were of the form $3\times2^k$, then $k$ can not be greater than $3$. So in total we get $2,4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 24.$

I was about to say it is not saying much to me, thank you

Are you sure cube powers of 3 are admitted? My professor solved this mentally, and spell out the solution without writing  .The answer was 2,4,3,6,12, but who knows it could be the rush. Can't remember the procedure, but I remember the answer

$24$ is $8$ into $3$ @some_math_guy. Cube powers of $2$ are allowed. You have the structure when $m$ is a power of $2$ in your question.

I remember he said that if prime powers had exponents greater than 2, characters could map to non-real roots of unity , so they would not be real

@some_math_guy not for 8. What is the structure of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}^*$?

it's ⟨−1⟩×⟨5⟩, using the theorem

Which is Z2\times Z2.

and what does that tell me?

As I said if we had that the structure of the group looks like $\mathbb{Z}{2}\times ...\times \mathbb{Z}{2}$. Then all elements would have order $1$ or $2$, so all charecters would be real.
